# Is there a way to get Tor "for free"? (free as in time, not money)

Tags: tor

I'm wondering if there's a way to get the functionality for Tor in Firefox (or my general OS) for "free", meaning that I spend 10 minutes setting up part of the functionality to work and skip the parts of Tor that will take an hour.

I'm completely aware that this is not an actual protection against tracking. I'm also aware that my information *will* be leaked.

I ask this because I don't actually have a lot of sensitive information that anyone would be interested in; I'm not someone who governments, etc. would want to have tracked beyond the norm. Basically I am interested in protecting my privacy, but as it doesn't matter whether it really works or not, I'd like to get as much as I easily can.

Did that all make sense? If it didn't I'll edit the question.

Comment: It doesn't make sense, if you are interested in protecting your privacy why would it not matter if it works?

Comment: As GdD says, if you are going to put up with the downsides of TOR, why would you not actually configure it to protect you? If it isn't important then don't use it. Seriously. Also, TOR isn't necessarily for protecting your information. You may want to look further into what it does.

Comment: right, i (think i) understand what it does. basically i'm asking if i can get partial tor functionality without dealing with any downsides.

Comment: If you're looking for a moderate amount of privacy with ease of use, you might be better off with a web proxy or VPN (there are paid and free versions). It's likely to be faster than Tor, but not nearly as effective at hiding your browser activity. http://www.proxysp.com/web-proxies/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Download and extract the Tor browser bundle.  It includes a preconfigured version of Firefox and tor setup to work together.